# AngularJS ignoring Set-Cookie header in certain cases

Tags: angularjs, cookies

basically my problems is use set-cookie header with angular (looks like he is ignored even with the withCredentials set to true) but here is the problem if i make the same request the cookies go, but if i change the path does't work.

Example;

```
POST http://localhost/app/api/oauth/ HTTP/1.1
[other headers and payload]
```

then i get the answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: ; expires=Wed, 31-Mar-2015 01:34:53 GMT
```

and send a request to access a resource:

```
GET http://localhost/app/api/oauth/test HTTP/1.1
Cookie:blah=something;
```

until now evething is ok, but when i try to access other resources on my server:

```
GET http://localhost/app/api/othercontroller/test HTTP/1.1
```

the cookie is not send anymore, only if i access some path after the path that create the cookie.

that is what network monitor show me. But i can't see that blah coockie on the resource tab (on cookie area).

Note: i already try use secure cookie or not and use http only cookie or not and all combinations between both of then. And i try don't use CORS or enable CORS, but anyone work too.

Anyone know what can be ?
Thanks for you time and patience.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's cookie storage to debug your cookie?

Comment: yeah, that is weird, the debug don't show. It's like he ignore the command Set-Cookie, but when i send to the same path the cookie go. I'm very confused with that.

Comment: `Set-Cookie: ; Domain=foo.com; Path=/;  expires=Wed, 31-Mar-2015 01:34:53 GMT` try this.

Comment: You right, is the path, when i put, everything works great.
Very very thanks, you made my day, i search for this all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm pasting my suggestion from my comment.*

Your initial cookie is set in a response of a HTTP endpoint path that is deeper than your second request.

```
Set-Cookie: ; Domain=foo.com; Path=/; expires=Wed, 31-Mar-2015 01:34:53 GMT
```

You may specify where to put your cookie by specifying a `Path` parameter in your response header like given above.